# Gravitation: Collision of a satellite and Meteorite

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, collision, centrifugal-force

[image: Ques]

> A satellite is orbiting around a planet in a circular path of radius $R$. A meteorite of mass $m$ collides with the satellite and sticks to the satellite. After collision, the satellite is seen to have gone into an orbit whose minimum distance from the planet is $R/2$. Mass of satellite is $9 m$ and that of planet is $M$ and assume that the meteorite is moving radially towards the satellite’s orbit with speed $v$ before collision as shown in the figure. If $v=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{86GM}{nR}}$, find the value of $n$.

My approach is here please guide me
[image: Myapproach]

Comment: This question could be improved by explaining your approach in words, stating where specifically you are confused, and typesetting your work using MathJax.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to use MathJax

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/311665) is a basic tutorial on MathJax. It's not too hard to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good question and can be solved using simple conservation laws of physics.

Firstly ,
assuming R > R/2 > Rm , we can totally neglect the radius of the planet(Rm).

I'm trying to split the components of velocity along radial and tangential axis.

**before collision**,

*Radial Velocity*(towards the planet) of the system is only from asteroid, i.e in this case $v$ (to be given as $\sqrt{\frac{86GM}{nR}}$

*Tangential Velocity* (tangential to orbit of satellite) of the system is only from the orbital velocity of the satellite. Let this be $v_s$ . The value of $v_s$ is $\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$.

**after collision**,
let the total mass of satellite and meteorite be $m_t = m_s + m_m$ where
$m_m = m$,
$m_s = 9m$,
$m_t = 10m$

*Radial velocity,*

This can be found out by conserving linear momentum in the radial axis ,
$m_t*v_r$ = $m_m*v$
on substituting values for $m_t $ and $ m_m$ we get $v_r = v/10$

*Tangential velocity,*

Again conserving linear momentum before and after collision on tangential axis we get
$m_t*v_t$ = $m_s*v_s$
after substitution $v_t$ = $\frac{9v_s}{10}$ =  $\frac{9}{10}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$

Since there is a collision the orbit of the satellite now shifts to an elliptical orbit. Here is a rough image on how it is:[image]

Now, in this orbit we can conserve angular momentum of the satellite about the center of the planet (and meteorite stuck inside it) at the spot of collision and at lowest point of which is given to R/2.

*Note : we should only take the velocity perpendicular to the direction vector of the body to the center of the planet, i.e the tangential part of the  velocity of the satellite.*

at point R/2 (where distance of satellite from planet) , you have to understand that there is only tangential velocity to the system and no radial velocity. let this tangential velocity be $v'$,

**on conserving angular momentum** at these 2 points,
$m_tv_tR$ = $m_tv'\frac{R}{2}$

Here we  find the velocity $v'$ to be as $\frac{9}{5}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$.

Now we can seal the deal by conserving Total energy at point R and R/2 .

At point R we have to **take energy of radial and tangential parts after collision** because ,**there is some loss in energy** due to the fact that this is an **inelastic collision** and also the elliptical orbit which the body follows **arises from the energy after collision** and not the energy before the collision . I think this is where you went wrong in your attempt.

so equating $T_R$ and $T_{R/2}$

$\frac{1}{2}m_t[v_r^2 + v_t^2] - \frac{GMm_t}{R} $ = $\frac{1}{2}m_tv'^2 - \frac{GMm_t}{R/2}$

$m_t$ can be cancelled on both sides and substituting $v_t$ = $\frac{9}{10}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$ , $v_r$ = $v/10$ and $v'$ =  $\frac{9}{5}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$

now it is only a matter of solving and finding value of v directly, I'm not going to solve it over here but you will get coefficients like 243 - 200 which 86/2 .

Hopefully you find this helpful, the beauty of this question is that you are applying all the high school knowledge in collisions, gravitation and conservation.

This seems like a question asked in JEE mock tests.

Comment: Yes it was asked in JEE Adv. Mock Test